# VScodevim how to jump to a really big column position

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscodevim, long-lines

I use `vscodevim` plugin in `vscode`.

I know `h` for left and `l` for right, I need to jump to a really big column position, for example, 19001129, I typed `19001129l`, it only jumped to column 99999. Is there a maximum value? How to make it bigger?

Comment: Have you tried with vanilla vim? The count in vim is type long, it is much greater than your number, it should not be a problem. Here both `|`(pipe) and `l`(lower L) support a more than 99999 count.

Comment: I use `vscodevim` plugin. Please check this https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim. I didn't try `vi` from command line for this case.

Comment: You should tell us that information! It's a vim "simulator" instead of a vim editor. Also you should tag it with this plugin instead of vim. Because it is not vim. Sorry, I don't use vscode, because I have vim.